# How to get lat and long from baidu maps for multiple location?

Tags: swift, baidu

I have multiple locations and want to find latitude and longitude from baidu map. Is that possible that I can send multiple location in 1 API call and it returns me all the lat and long of multiple places? Or I need to call API multiple time? As this is not a good way. Please suggest and give me solution for this.I have followed code from here to integrate baidu map: https://github.com/SemperIdem/BaiduMapSDKDemo-Swift

Comment: Add comment if my question is wrong don't down vote directly , mention first why you think its not valid

Comment: This is a question about he BaiduMap API. You'd better ask them directly or search their documentation, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

We can't put address array because   `[geocoder geocodeAddressString: completionHandler:]` use string value. We have to used
**asynchronous geocode request in a synchronous manner**, and then you can just add the requests to a serial queue and the requests will be performed sequentially rather than in parallel.

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *mapItems = [NSMutableArray array];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;   // make it a serial queue

NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:nil];
}];

NSArray *addresses = @[@"Mumbai, India", @"Delhi, India", @"Bangalore, India"];

for (NSString *address in addresses) {
    NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            } else if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
                CLPlacemark *geocodedPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:geocodedPlacemark.location.coordinate
                                                               addressDictionary:geocodedPlacemark.addressDictionary];
                MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
                [mapItem setName:geocodedPlacemark.name];

                [mapItems addObject:mapItem];
            }
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        }];

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }];

    [completionOperation addDependency:operation];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
}

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:completionOperation];
```